# How do I use the parent div to contain & move rotated spans?

Tags: html, css, css-position

How do I use the parent div (#warped) to move and contain, my rotated span elements (which are in fact 'curved words' that I want to keep in said position) in one movement?

I have used this link to help generate the curvature: http://csswarp.eleqtriq.com/

The `<span>` tags are placed within the `#warped` parent element in my HTML document, but despite this on the webpage itself they appear to be located outside of `#warped` div

I would like to, for example, move the entire curved word to the left of the page. How would I do this?

Here is the CSS:

```
#warped {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}

#warped>span[class^=w]:nth-of-type(n+0) {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

#warped span {
 font-family: 'ABeeZee';
 font-size: 38px;
 font-weight: regular;
 font-style: normal;
 line-height: 0.65;
 white-space: pre;
 overflow: visible;
 padding: 0px;
}

#warped .w0 {
 transform: rotate(0.91rad);
 width: 20px;
 height: 24px;
 left: 552.15px;
 top: 152.55px;
}

#warped .w1 {
 transform: rotate(1.06rad);
 width: 23px;
 height: 24px;
 left: 565.17px;
 top: 174.68px;
}

    etc etc
```

Here is the HTML as well:

```
<div id='warped'>
 <span class='w0'>F</span><span class='w1'>a</span><span class='w2'>n</span><span class='w3'>t</span><span class='w4'>a</span><span class='w5'>s</span><span class='w6'>t</span><span class='w7'>i</span><span class='w8'>c</span><span class='w9'>!</span><span class='w10'>!</span><span class='w11'>!</span><span class='w12'>!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: i am confused what do you want. 1) move word to left (isn't that happening already?) 2) make curved words? (right now all letters are jumbled together..?

Comment: I would like to have the freedom to move the curved words using their container, #warped, so that if i were the float the container left it would do so, or if I wanted to center the #warped element with all its child elements contained too, I could do so

Comment: They are already doing what you want them to. You have just set ridiculous values like `left: 565.17px; top: 174.68px;` in `#warped .w1` to make it seem like they aren't. Your code is doing what you're telling it to. Try moving `#warped` and you'll see that your text moves too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `position:absolute` and `display:block` on the `span` elements. Change it to:

```
#warped>span[class^=w]:nth-of-type(n+0) {
 display: inline-block;
 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}
```

As long as you don´t have a specified width on your `#warped` it will be 100% of the browser and the text will look like it's outside.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/54L30x1j/

Basically on their site: http://csswarp.eleqtriq.com/, you can re-size the window and make it small. Then your self you can further reduce the extra size. Put your text in top left corner as much as possible.

```
<div id='warped'> <span class='w0'>F</span><span class='w1'>a</span><span class='w2'>n</span><span class='w3'>t</span><span class='w4'>a</span><span class='w5'>s</span><span class='w6'>t</span><span class='w7'>i</span><span class='w8'>c</span>

</div>

<p>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum quasi ad ipsum cum ipsa repellendus recusandae in molestias fugiat placeat maiores aspernatur numquam neque id blanditiis. Iusto amet odio natus.</span>
    <span>Ipsam quas incidunt deserunt molestias asperiores deleniti temporibus quisquam vel sapiente dolores aliquam eum optio minus cupiditate ipsum illo veritatis eligendi obcaecati porro ea rerum dolore repudiandae neque earum voluptatem.</span>
    <span>Totam officiis saepe tenetur tempore voluptate cupiditate fugit exercitationem voluptatem illum possimus. Dicta similique dolore laboriosam ipsum modi minus saepe accusantium consectetur natus architecto harum commodi porro eius est nemo.</span>
    <span>Officiis labore quibusdam modi autem velit neque reiciendis unde quaerat delectus expedita consectetur nemo nobis assumenda officia porro cum quos voluptates molestiae enim debitis commodi saepe id dolorum. Repudiandae repellat.</span>
    <span>Aspernatur non nobis nesciunt deserunt possimus nulla repellat voluptatibus fuga asperiores error optio ipsa adipisci voluptate quidem esse commodi recusandae molestias dolores iure minima sapiente laborum molestiae dolor quisquam ratione.</span>
</p>
```